# Unable to open Firefox browser with given URL using Java on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, firefox

I am new in Automation testing.
Had created a simple program to Open URL in Firefox browser. Browser is getting opened without URL.
Someone please help.

```
package    sanitytest;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Adminlogin {

    public static void main(String[]args){

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); 

        driver.get("http://www.gcrit.com/build3/admin/login.php");

    }
}
```

I am using Firefox version :- 47.0.1
eclipse mars version  :- 4.5.0
Selenium webdriver version  :- 2.51

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Mozila Firefox till version 46.x it was the legacy browser and we didn't need gecko driver. Mozila Firefox from version 47.x onwards comes with Marionette, which is an automation driver for Mozilla's Gecko engine. It can remotely control either the UI or the internal JavaScript of a Gecko platform, such as Firefox. Can be donwloaded here: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases and needs selenium 3.x.

So, either downgrade FF to version 46.x, or use latest selenium binding with geckodriver + latest FF

Comment: You have mentioned `till version 47.x` & OP is using the same FF 47.0.1. Why are you asking to `downgrade FF to version 46.x`?

Comment: It helped me a lot. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Selenium WebDriver 2.51.0 is not compatible with Firefox 47.0. The WebDriver component which handles Firefox browsers (`FirefoxDriver`) will be discontinued.

Try using firefox 46.0.1. It best matches with Selenium 2.51

https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/

Comment: It helped me a lot. Thank you very much.

Comment: @anjitasinha You are Welcome

Answer (score 0):

try the following code its working 
    package automation ;

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

enter code here

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class test {
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
//Object webdriver;
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", 
"C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\geckodriver-v0.17.0-win64/geckodriver.exe");

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(25, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("https://www.easybooking.lk");   
String i = driver.getCurrentUrl();
System.out.println(i);
//driver.close();

}

}
```

if its not working http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/ here download java 3.4.0

then in eclipse, right click your project-->properties-->java build path--> liberies-->add external JARS..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0e3F.jpg)